# Нужно ли каждый раз стартовать дебаггер?

Tags: android, android-studio

Можно ли в Android Studio дебажить сам проект, а не ставить определенные точки остановки? Хочу отследить полностью, а не по отдельным точкам. И можно ли не перезапускать каждый раз проект после изменений в коде?

Comment: Собственно, тут два вопроса. Первый мне вообще не понятен. А по второму: Instant Run либо платные аналоги.

Comment: без точек останова все равно не успеешь отслеживать

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja а какие есть платные аналоги ?

Comment: Поставьте точку остановки, на первом месте, где начинается проект и дебажте на здоровье шаг за шагом.

Comment: @elik, https://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel-for-android/